# Is there any way to send noraml keyboard commands to xbox via a usb cable from pc throught programming

Tags: c#, usb, driver, xbox360, xbox

Is there any way to send normal keyboard commands to xbox via a usb cable from pc throught programming

Needed answer asap.

Regards,
Apurva

Comment: can anybody answer this question as im in despirate need of this issue to be closed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to write a custom driver for windows that basically acts as a keyboard as far as the xbox is concerned. Then, on the windows side, you would use the driver to send keyboard commands across a Male-to-Male USB cable to the XBox.